# How can I align the icon according to the percentage of the progress bar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the percent indicator library and I need the icon to be aligned according to the percentage of the progress bar.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how are you placing the icon on top of the progress bar, but in case you are using a Stack this might help

```
Stack(
        children: [
          LinearProgressIndicator(
            value: _value,
            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red),
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
            minHeight: 40
          ),
          LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (context, constrains) {
                  //5 is just the right padding
                  var leftPadding = constrains.maxWidth * _value - _iconSize - 5; 
                  var topPadding = (constrains.maxHeight - _iconSize) / 2;
                  return Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: leftPadding, top: topPadding),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.airplanemode_active,
                      size: _iconSize.toDouble()
                    ),
                  );
                }
            )
        ]
      ),
```

Take a look at this codepen https://codepen.io/fcontreras-the-bashful/pen/GRZpRyg

Answer (score 2):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can remove `Wrap` and provide `width` , `height` and `value` to `ProgressBarView` 
and use `Transform.rotate` to rotate icon 
code snippet

```
Container(width: 400, height: 40, child: ProgressBarView(value: .9,)),
Divider(),
Container(width: 300, height: 40, child: ProgressBarView(value: .7,)),
Divider(),
Container(width: 100, height: 40, child: ProgressBarView(value: .4,)),
...
class ProgressBarView extends StatelessWidget {
ProgressBarView({this.value});
... 
    return Container(
          color: Color(0Xffe6e6e6),
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2, right: 2),
          child: Stack(fit: StackFit.loose, children: [
            LinearProgressIndicator(
                value: value,
                valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red),
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                minHeight: 40),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(width: 400, height: 40, child: ProgressBarView(value: .9,)),
            Divider(),
            Container(width: 300, height: 40, child: ProgressBarView(value: .7,)),
            Divider(),
            Container(width: 100, height: 40, child: ProgressBarView(value: .4,)),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ProgressBarView extends StatelessWidget {
  ProgressBarView({this.value});
  final value;
  final _iconSize = 30;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Color(0Xffe6e6e6),
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2, right: 2),
      child: Stack(fit: StackFit.loose, children: [
        LinearProgressIndicator(
            value: value,
            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red),
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
            minHeight: 40),
        LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constrains) {
          //5 is just the right padding
          print(constrains.maxWidth);
          var leftPadding = constrains.maxWidth * value - _iconSize;
          var topPadding = (constrains.maxHeight - _iconSize) / 2;
          return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: leftPadding, top: topPadding),
            child: Transform.rotate(
                angle: math.pi / 2,
                child: Icon(Icons.airplanemode_active,
                    size: _iconSize.toDouble())),
          );
        })
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```